# How to store multi-line textbox content before page is closed and retrieve it when page loads again?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, caching, redirect, textbox

I tried to find approaches in the Internet on how to store this data somewhere without saving it to the database and found strange silence about this issue.

I have a database and web page (user form) with a multi-line textboxes on it. Very often I do **Page.Response.Redirect** to reload the page with new parameters in the address string. It's ok if the data was previously saved to the database. But in many cases it shouldn't be done. And in these cases all textboxes just lose their text.

I have three conceptual approaches:

1) keep data in cache locally, which is something new to me, I don't know how;

2) use database anyway and keep temporary data in a temporary table;

3) may be I can use viewstate to save and load state for each particular control somehow.

Please, help me find a better way. If you have an idea, or know a useful detailed article, it would be great, guys. I need really practical information, abstractions are no good any more.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you are talking about HTML5's local storage this is not compatible with all browsers. So, unless you want to leave users of IE9 and below out, you have to user a server side approach

2) This works and I recommend this solution if you want to persist the data for long periods

3) Viewstate stores data in the page so if you redirect the user somewhere else it gets lost.

Other than this, you can keep the data in session: `Session["textarea_content"] = txtID.Text`. The data will be available during that session, which means that it expires when the user closes the browser or leaves it unattended.

---

So here are my recommendations:

- Use the viewstate if you only need the data while the user is in that specific page
- Use session if you only need the data while the user is active on the website
- Use the database if you want to keep the data available even if the user leaves

Comment: @Vladimir Store it in session for now. It's easier and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://slides.html5rocks.com/#offline-storage-title

Your best bet is to use local storage. (New in HTML 5, but supported by all the browsers now.)  That way, if someone never comes back, you don't store their data till the end of time.

An alternative is to store it in the session storage. (You are using a framework that takes care of this, right?). But that is harder to scale, and leaves you holding text for users that may or may not ever come back.

Comment: There are several libraries that simulate the storage API on older browsers. See the section on local storage: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

Answer (score 0):

you can use your first option but it will not always a best way

you can use session. store your whole string in session and retrieve it on load

i will recommend a session to be used.